# Java Connection Over LAN - Connection Refused: connect

Tags: java, eclipse, lan

I am trying to make a one way messaging system for an escape room so you can type messages in on one computer and they appear on the other. 
This works on one computer with localhost or 127.0.0.1, but on LAN with two computers it comes up with Connection refused: Connect. A few other people asked a similar question except nothing suggested there worked.
I have tried:

- Pinging the Server (worked)
- telnet 10.0.0.10 4676 (worked)
- Trying it on a single computer (worked for both computers)
- Swapping the server and client (didn't work)
- Changing the port (didn't work)
- Allowing Java through as a rule for both firewalls (didn't work)
- Searching for other firewall software on both computers (uninstalled one other programme but still didn't work)
- Tweaking Code to test if it's working (didn't work)
- Completely disabling both firewalls (didn't work)
- Running both the Server and the Client on the one computer and changing localhost/127.0.0.1 to the ipv4 of the computer (worked for both computers)
- Probably numerous other things I have forgotten about

If anyone can actually be bothered to dive through the code, I have marked all the important parts with nearby comments. (The code is written like this due to possible expansion of the programme later)

## Client

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Client extends JFrame{

private JTextField userText;
private JTextArea sentHints;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private Socket connection;
private String serverIP;
private String finalMessage;
public Client(String host){
    super("EscapeRoomHint-Client");
    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setEditable(false);
    sentHints = new JTextArea();
    sentHints.setEditable(false);

    userText.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                    userText.setText("");
                }
            }
            );
    add(userText,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(new JScrollPane(sentHints));
    setSize(800,400);
    setVisible(true);

}

public void startRunning(){
    try{
        connectToServer();    //Connect to server method
        setupStreams();       //Set up Streams
        sendingMessages();    //While running (basically a loop)
    }catch(EOFException a){
        showMessage("\nServer Closed");
    }catch(IOException a1){
        a1.printStackTrace();
        showMessage("\nServer Closed");
    }finally{
        closeConnection();
    }
}

private void connectToServer() throws IOException{ //connect to server method
    showMessage("\nConnecting...");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 4676); //Connects to the Server here
    showMessage("\nConnected");
}

private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    showMessage("\nStreams setup\n----------------------------------------\n");
}

private void sendingMessages(){

    userText.setEditable(true);
    while(true){

    }
}

private void closeConnection(){
    showMessage("\nClosing Connection");
    userText.setEditable(false);
    try{
        output.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException b){
        b.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String message){
    try {
        output.writeObject(message);
        output.flush();
        finalMessage = message;
        showMessage(message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void showMessage(String message){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        sentHints.append("\n" + message);
                    }
                }
            );
}   
}
```

## ClientBoot

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ClientBoot extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Client hintMessenger = new Client("10.0.0.10"); //inputs IP Address here
        hintMessenger.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        hintMessenger.startRunning(); //Run the start running method
    }
}
```

## Server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame{
    private JTextArea hintArea;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket connection;

    public Server(){
        super("EscapeRoomHint-Server");
        hintArea = new JTextArea();
        hintArea.setEditable(false);
        add(hintArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(800,400);
        setVisible(true);
        }

public void startRunning(){

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(4676, 2); //Set up server socket (4676)
            while(true){

                try {
                    waitForConnection(); //program sits around and waits for people to join
                    setupStreams(); //if they join then set up streams
                    whileRunning(); //loop waiting to receive messages
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        showMessage("Failed To Connect");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        closeConnection();
    }

}

private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    connection = server.accept();            //accept connection here

}
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
}
private void whileRunning() throws IOException{
    String message = "";
    do{
        try{
            message=(String) input.readObject();
                showMessage(message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException a){
            showMessage("An error Occurred");
        }
    }while(true);
}
private void closeConnection(){
    try{
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException a){
        a.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private void showMessage(String message){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        hintArea.setText(message);
                    }
                }
            );
}
}
```

## ServerBoot

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ServerBoot extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Server hintMessenger = new Server();
        hintMessenger.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        hintMessenger.startRunning();         //run the startRunning method
    }

}
```

I have been trying to solve this problem for countless hours and I'm finally beat. Does anyone know a possible fix?

EDIT: I finally solved it! It wasn't a problem with the networking, but in the code. I fixed it by adding serverIP = host; in the constructor.

Comment: Did you try having the server listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost/127.0.0.1?

Comment: In the server when you construct the serversocket, can you try omiting the backlog paramater in the constructor and instantiate it like this `server = new ServerSocket(4676);`

Comment: @jackarms Do you mean when testing on the one computer?

Comment: @SteelToe I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Can you check your router settings to see if it's allowing all incoming connections?

Comment: @SteelToe Wouldn't that only be useful if the connections are coming from outside the network. eg over the internet?

Comment: Listening on 0.0.0.0 should work for one or more computers, listening on localhost will only work for a single computer.